# Simple jQuery Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

This will be my first time creating one of those slider things. I've seen quite a few of them, and although they're very cool, i'm looking for something that's very basic. As you can see in the image below, I have 4 rectangular images to the right, and when any one of them is clicked, some text to the left will be displayed that corresponds to the image that was just clicked.

I'm not sure if jQuery would be needed to do this? I'd assume it'd be a lot easier than Javascript...

Can anyone please point me in the right direction or offer some advice on how I should go about creating a slider like this?

Thank you

[image: Sample jQuery Slider Image]

Comment: I don't see the image. But, I hope you know that jquery *is* javascript.

Comment: no, jquery would not be 'needed', and this kinda seems like a, drop off your design and pick up the code later, that's not what this site is.  Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Do you want already completed ones, or do you want to make one yourself for a learning experience?

Comment: Ah okay, that's not a slider. That's an accordion.

Comment: @jondavidjohn, I'm not expecting code. @Loktar, I am wanting to make one for the learning experience, but just don't know which would be the best way to create one, or even how they are made. @Alan, yeah, I know jQuery *is* Javascript. I'm not that much of a noob. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great tutorial on creating what you have in the image. It uses jquery but jquery is not a requirement when it comes to making things like this.

http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-simple-horizontal-accordion/

Comment: Thank you @Loktar, I will check that link out now. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something alot of people use is a script called jquery kwicks. Here is a link to a simple image accordion that might help you get started:

http://www.aoclarkejr.com/tutorial-jquery-accordion-slider.html

Here is a link to the kwicks site:

http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks

Answer (score 1):

TO implement a simple yet powerful image slider, below is my code which I have executed successfully.
Below is the code to create a simple Image Slider using JavaScript.

You can append as many images you want by creating instances of the Image() object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"

 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Image Slider</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image();
image1.src = "AshuBridgeBW.jpg";

var image2 = new Image();
image2.src = "Ashu.jpg";

var image3 = new Image();
image3.src = "A&S.jpg";
</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="club.png" name="slide" width="300" height="300" border="10" />
<script>
var step=1;
function slideit(){
    document.images.slide.src=eval("image"+step+".src");
    if(step<3){
        step++;}
    else{
        step=1;}
    setTimeout("slideit()",1000);
}
slideit();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What could possibly cause you to use `eval("image"+step+".src")` over `"image"+step+".src"`? You shouldn't be `eval`ing code in your timeout, either; use `setTimeout(slideit, 1000)` instead.